# Yarn environment variable set up in Ubuntu

Tags: yarnpkg

In the yarn installation doc it is mentioned as below:

```
 Add this to your profile: export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-[version]/bin"
```

But it is not working for me.
Can anyone explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin
```

Still, this won't be permanent, each reboot will start with the past $PATH.